# Compile less files with grunt-contrib-less won't work

Tags: node.js, less, gruntjs

I'm using Grunt for building my web project. I installed `grunt-contrib-less` package und added a task to my `grunt.initConfig({..});`

```
less : {
            options: {
                paths: ['js/base']
            },
            files: {
                'js/base/*.css' : 'js/base/*.less'
            }
        }
```

when I run the target *less* via `grunt less`, it runs without errors but doesn't compile the less file to a css file.

```
Running "less:files" (less) task

Done, without errors.
```

I have installed the *lessc* package via node, too. Doing `lessc <source> <dest>` works fine.

Currently I have pointed with the *files option* directly to one dir which contains one less file for testing. Even if I write the whole file name into *files option*, it happens nothing...

Later on I want to scan the whole js directory and compile all new modified *.less files.

I have installed following versions:

```
grunt-cli v0.1.6
grunt v0.4.0
node v0.8.7
npm 1.1.49
```

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The glob pattern `js/base/*.css` does not match any files, therefore there is no destination. Usually, tasks like this expect multiple inputs to combine into a single output. Also, bear in mind that `less` is a **multi-task**, and putting `files` as a child of `less` is not doing what you expect. (it is treating it as a target, not a src/dest map)

If you want a 1-1 transform of .less into .css, you can use [dynamic expansion](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically). (or you can define each src/dest pair manually, but who wants to do that?)

In your case:

```
less: {
    options: {
        paths: ['js/base']
    },
    // target name
    src: {
        // no need for files, the config below should work
        expand: true,
        cwd:    "js/base",
        src:    "*.less",
        ext:    ".css"
    }
}
```

Comment: big thanks, that worked. Also I learned something about dynamic expressions in grunt ;)

Comment: I am doing this the same way but get problems with variables being loaded to late and therefor not being accessible when less files are being compiled to css. This is my output. Any idea?

Running "less:development" (less) task
>> NameError: variable @baseLineHeight is undefined in node_modules/twitter-bootstrap/less/accordion.less on line 8, column 18:
>> 7 .accordion {
>> 8   margin-bottom: @baseLineHeight;
>> 9 }

Comment: For grunt-contrib-less v0.10.0, the configuration should be: ```less: { options: {...}, files: {...} }```. Property name should be `files`, not `src`.

Comment: @Timo did you figure out how to load your variable less file(s) first?

Comment: @chandlervdw Sorry I did not.

Answer (score 9):

I used Anthonies solution but stil had an error

```
Warning: Object true has no method indexOf
```

If I changed the order putting `expand true` as second it gave me the error

```
Unable to read "less" file
```

where "less" was the value of the first item in my list.

I solved it by changing files into an array like this:

```
less: {
    options: {

            paths: ["js/base"]
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: "js/base",
            src: ["**/*.less"],
            dest: "js/base",
            ext: ".css"
        }]
},
```

I used `"grunt-contrib-less" : "^0.11.0"`

Comment: excellent, the previous examples were not working for me either. files:[{...}] did the job.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me, but modified to reflect this scenario:

```
less: {
    options: {
        paths: ["js/base"]
    },
    files: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: "js/base",
        src: ["**/*.less"],
        dest: "js/base",
        ext: ".css"
    }
},
```