# grunt replace all less files into css files

Tags: javascript, less, gruntjs, glob

I use grunt to convert all my less files into css files,using this:

```
less: {
  development: {
    files: {
      "css/*.css": "less/*.less"
    }
  }
}
```

This worked on version 0.3.0, but now that I have upgraded to v0.4.0 it doesn't work anymore.

The following code (not using * in the destination) works on both versions, so the problem is with the star on the destination file.

```
less: {
  development: {
    files: {
      "css/test.css": "less/*.less"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: definitely pointing you to http://gruntjs.com/contributing, if you find a bug in software you use, report it. (if it worked, and after upgrading it doesn't, the people who made your software are the first group to ask). They have an IRC channel, that's going to be the fastest route to an answer.

Comment: This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094667/compile-less-files-with-grunt-contrib-less-wont-work

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This isn't a bug. Grunt no longer supports globbing in `dest` using that configuration. However, you can use the "files array" format, like this:

```
files: [
  {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'src',
    src: ['*.less'],
    dest: 'assets/css/',
    ext: '.css'
  }
]
```

Also, if you use a library like Bootstrap and you want to build each LESS file (component) into a separate, individual CSS file, it's not very easy to accomplish "out of the box". The reason is that each LESS file would need to have its own `@import` statements for `variables.less` and `mixins.less` (and a couple of others like `forms.less` and `navbar.less`, since they are referenced in other files).

To make this really easy, try the Grunt plugin, [assemble-less](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-less) (disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainers of the project, and I'm also on the core team for less.js). assemble-less is a fork of grunt-contrib-less by Tyler Kellen, but it adds some experimental features that will accomplish what you need (if you want stability, please stick with grunt-contrib-less). For example:

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

  less: {
    // Compile all targeted LESS files individually
    components: {
      options: {
        imports: {
          // Use the new "reference" directive, e.g.
          // @import (reference) "variables.less";
          reference: [
            "bootstrap/mixins.less", 
            "bootstrap/variables.less" 
          ]
        }
      },
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bootstrap/less',
          // Compile each LESS component excluding "bootstrap.less", 
          // "mixins.less" and "variables.less" 
          src: ['*.less', '!{boot,var,mix}*.less'],
          dest: 'assets/css/',
          ext: '.css'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

The `imports` feature essentially prepends the specified `@import` statements onto the source files. The `reference` option allows you to "reference" other less files while only outputting styles that are specifically referenced via mixins or `:extend`. You might need to reference a few more files than shown here, since Bootstrap cross-references styles from other components, like forms.less, buttons.less, etc. (See [the Gruntfile in assemble-less](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-less/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) for examples.)

So after running the `assemble-less` task with the configuration in the example above, the `assets/css` folder would have:

- `alerts.css`
- `badges.css`
- `breadcrumbs.css`
- `button-groups.css`
- `buttons.css`
- `carousel.css`
- `close.css`
- `code.css`
- `component-animations.css`
- `dropdowns.css`
- `forms.css`
- `glyphicons.css`
- `grid.css`
- `input-groups.css`
- `jumbotron.css`
- `labels.css`
- `list-group.css`
- `media.css`
- `modals.css`
- `navbar.css`
- `navs.css`
- `normalize.css`
- `pager.css`
- `pagination.css`
- `panels.css`
- `popovers.css`
- `print.css`
- `progress-bars.css`
- `responsive-utilities.css`
- `scaffolding.css`
- `tables.css`
- `theme.css`
- `thumbnails.css`
- `tooltip.css`
- `type.css`
- `utilities.css`
- `wells.css`

There are other features that should help you with this, but the **`imports`** feature is super powerful since it allows you to add directives directly to the Gruntfile.

Comment: what do you mean no longer support ? do you mean for the less directive ? or for any dest parameters ?