# how to make LESS hat library mixins globally available

Tags: css, less

Is there some way I would be able to tell a LESS compiler to include the [LESS hat library](http://lesshat.com/) for everything it compiles (that is, without specifically writing an `@import` directive in every file that I want to use it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Grunt.js plugin called [assemble-less](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-less) for compiling LESS to CSS that does what you need. I just answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597839/grunt-replace-all-less-files-into-css-files) (not a duplicate though) with info about the assemble-less plugin because it fit their situation as well. Lol I'm really not trying to spam about assemble-less, I just don't know of another plugin that does that.

If you haven't used Grunt.js, it's awesome. Don't give up until you figure it out, you'll love yourself for it ;-)

Comment: Hey thats awesome man, thats exactly the type of thing I was looking for. I switched to using SASS because it has compass but ive always liked the less syntax a little better so its good to see new tools and utilities like this coming out. I notice grunt being used everywhere too so its probably inevitable that ill have to figure it out soon anyway. Thanks a lot! Going to try this out as soon as i can.

Comment: glad it helped! let me know if you need help getting it figured out